# remove files via ssh and xargs

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, xargs

I am trying to remove files via ssh  using by find and xargs. On the local machine command works correctly. I am using exception list also.

I have tried to changes brackets between ' ' and " " but it does not work.

```
save_files=(test1 test2)
```

On the local machine:

```
find / -mindepth 1 | grep -vE "$(IFS=\| && echo "${save_files[*]}")" | xargs rm -rf
```

via ssh:

```
su - user -c "ssh host find / -mindepth 1 | grep -vE '$(IFS=\| && echo "${save_files[*]}")' | xargs rm -rf"
```

In above ssh command xargs is performing locally. I need xargs on remote machine. Even I put find command in '' brackets like below:

```
su - user -c "ssh host 'find / -mindepth 1 | grep -vE '$(IFS=\| && echo "${save_files[*]}")' | xargs rm -rf'"
```

Comment: As a side note, removing anything under '/' not matching a dynamic pattern is a risky operation. If there is a problem in the pattern, there is a potential to remove too many files

Comment: '/' is only example here, in my case I use other directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting another answer, trying again for one-liner, avoiding the intermediate script.

The key problem is the three level quoting, whereas shell support only two level quoting (double quote, single quote). I believe it might be possible to eliminate the need for the 3rd level of quoting by using backquote in the pattern, eliminating the need to put it into quotes.

```
IFS=\| P="${save_files[*]}"   su - owner -c "ssh localhost 'set -vx ; find /tmp/xyz -mindepth 1 | grep -vE ${P//|/\\|} | xargs rm -rf'"
```

The solution create the pattern with 'escapes' - see '($P/|/\|}', eliminating the need to quote the pattern. Should work if the save_files does not have magic characters.

Notes:

1. Notice that I've replaced '/' with /tmp/xyz, to reduce the change the accidental copy/paste will remove important data (already happen on my VM :-( ).
2. The 'set -vx' is for debugging & troubleshooting, and can be removed

Comment: seems to works! I have to test it a little bit deeper with my cases but command generally works fine. Thanks a lot! I will back after do some tests.

Comment: almost works fine but if save_files include more than 2 files rest of them has problem. There is missed \ before |
+ save_files=(test1 test2 test.ini test4)
+ IFS='|'
+ P='test1|test2|sapftp.ini|test4'
+ su - user -c 'ssh host '\''find /tmp/xyz -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1| grep -vE test1\|test2|test.ini|test4 | xargs ls -l'\'''
test4: Command not found.
test.ini: Command not found.

Comment: @mac thanks for pointing this out. Script modified to handle as many arguments as needed using the ${P/|//\\|} (double //)

Comment: With  (double //) it still afects only first pipe:
su - user -c "ssh host 'find /tmp/xyz -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1| grep -vE ${P/|//\\|} | xargs ls -l'"

error the same as before - for 3th nad 4th filenames command not found.

Comment: @mac Oops, I placed the 'double /' in the wrong location. Should have been ${P//.../...} ,and not ${P/...//...}

Comment: thanks a lot! It works correctly. I just need to find some explanation for  this pattern part to understand deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
su - user -c "ssh host 'save_files=test; find / -mindepth 1 | grep -vE "$save_files" | xargs rm -rf'"
```

Or after switching as root user try below one?

```
ssh host 'save_files=test; find / -mindepth 1 | grep -vE "$save_files" | xargs rm -rf'
```

Comment: first  one:
save_files=test: Command not found

Find almost fine but with exception which should be skip. 
Second one not fit to my case. I have to this with switch user and then ssh. Btw. I discovered that in my commands the problem is with 'su - user -c' beacuse it works without it. With 'su - user -c' xargs is removing not found files but files in current directory on local machine.

Comment: If you can execute as a cronjob, then you can get rid of su option by setting a cronjob with ssh command in bash script.

Comment: It is a part of bash script generally but script is running as a root user. Remote host connection works only with 'user' that why I have to switch by 'su' from root.

Comment: Did you tried with ssh -i option? ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@x.x.x.x

Comment: With ssh -i it is asking about passphrase for key, so it is not correct in my case. I have to login without password. 

I also tried instead find and xargs rm like: su - user -c "ssh host cd directory;rm !(test)" but it return "badly placed ()'s.

Answer (score 0):

The code for executing the command on a remote host:

```
su - user -c "ssh host 'find / -mindepth 1 | grep -vE '$(IFS=\| && echo "${save_files[*]}")' | xargs rm -rf'"
```

Is using double quote to pass the command to 'su -c', and then single quotes to pass the command to 'ssh' (which contain double quotes). However, the quoting does not support nesting, so that the quote in '$(IFS=... ... )' actually terminate the quote in 'find'.

You can execute the same with a 'set -vx' prefix, to see the expansion

```
su - owner -c "set -vx ; ssh localhost ...
```

and you will see

```
++ IFS='|'
++ echo 'test1|test2'
+ su - owner -c 'set -vx ; ssh localhost '\''set -x ; find /foo -mindepth 1 | grep -vE '\''test1|test2'\'' | xargs rm -rf'\'''
Password: 
+ ssh localhost 'set -x ; find /foo -mindepth 1 | grep -vE test1'
+ 'test2 | xargs rm -rf'
-su: test2 | xargs rm -rf: command not found
+ find /foo -mindepth 1
+ grep -vE test1
find: ‘/foo’: No such file or directory
```

**Proposed Solution:**

I was not able to find a way to get three level quoting (very frustrating)  Possible solution may be to create a helper script h.sh, which will perform the 'ssh' command, and then invoking the helper script with 'su - user '/path/to/helper.sh'

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am trying build this script as a one file so I am still looking for solution to this command or any other which allow to remove files with exceptions.

Comment: @mac I've posted a new answer going for a single line. Can you try, and let me know ?

Answer (score -1):

First connect your Remote system and run the bash command whatever you need, like find and xargs

```
ssh root@MachineB 'bash command'
```

Comment: I need use this in way:
su - user -c "ssh..." 

beacuse I perform that as an user root and do not want type password's (user has ssh key with remote host)